# Firefox add-on sdk - worker.tab is null when using window.open

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, window.open

Used Firefox version 39.0.3:

Goal is to inject some code to every loaded document and to use worker.tab and worker.port.
Accessing the worker.tab in "onAttach:" of the "sdk/page-mod" fails in a new Firefox window if it was opened by a Javascript function, using window.open(). 
It can be reproduced with this simple jpm add-on, here are the sources:

index.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
 include: ["*", "file://*"],
 contentScript: "",
 attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
 onAttach: function(worker) {
   console.log(worker.tab.url);
 }
});
```

page.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      function openwin(url,winobject){
        window.open(url,winobject, "width=1024,height=768"); 
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>
      <a id="openwindow" href="javascript:openwin('./subPage.html','sub')">Open subwindow</a>
    </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

subPage.html:

```
<html>
  <title>SubPage</title>
  <body>
    <h1>Sub Window</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
TypeError: worker.tab is null
Stack-Trace:
.onAttach@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://experimental-addon/index.js:7:4
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:104:9
@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/page-mod.js:175:7
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:104:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:115:45
@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/worker.js:160:3
dispatch@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/method/core.js:119:12
@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/page-mod.js:186:3
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:104:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:104:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:115:45
frameMessageReceived@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/remote/parent.js:152:32
```

Everything works fine if I close the subPage.html and reopen it using Ctrl+Shift+N.

Comment: See related Firefox bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=989288

Comment: A work around is to divert window.open to a tab, see option [browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction) in about:config